# ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que una calculadora opere más de dos dígitos en Java?

Tags: java, java-swing

He estado intentando hacer una calculadora en JFrame y no he podido hacer que sume más de dos dígitos.

Tengo aquí el código que estoy utilizando (probablemente tenga algo terriblemente mal en él):

```
pantalla.append("=");

        String texto = pantalla.getText();
        String regexnumeros = "\\s*[0-9]+=";
        String regexoperadores = "\\s*[+-x/]+";
        String[] numeros = texto.split(regexoperadores);
        String[] operadores = texto.split(regexnumeros);

        for (int i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++) {

            switch (operadores[0]) {
                case "+":
                    resultado += Integer.parseInt(numeros[i]);
                    break;
                case "-":
                    resultado -= Integer.parseInt(numeros[i]);
                    break;
                case "x":
                    resultado *= Integer.parseInt(numeros[i]);
                    break;
                case "/":
                    resultado /= Integer.parseInt(numeros[i]);
                    break;
                default:
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "OPERADOR INVALIDO");
            }
        }

        pantalla.append(String.valueOf(resultado));
```

Todo eso se encuentra dentro del `ActionListener` del botón del igual ("=").

Answer (score 0):

Copie tu código y lo modifique un poco, no me funciono como lo tenias así que hice modificaciones, si a ti te funcionan esas partes dejalas así y solo cambia lo que no.

```
        String texto = pantalla.getText().replace("x","*");
        pantalla.append("=");
        

        String regexnumeros = "[0-9]";
        String regexoperadores = "[+\\-*/]";
        String[] numeros = texto.split(regexoperadores);
        String[] operadores = texto.split(regexnumeros);

        resultado = Integer.parseInt(numeros[0]);
        int numero;

        for (int i = 1; i < numeros.length; i++) {
            numero = Integer.parseInt(numeros[i]);
            switch (operadores[i]) {
                case "+":
                    resultado += numero;
                    break;
                case "-":
                    resultado -= numero;
                    break;
                case "*":
                    resultado *= numero;
                    break;
                case "/":
                    resultado /= numero;
                    break;
                default:
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "OPERADOR INVALIDO");
            }
        }
            pantalla.append(String.valueOf(resultado));
```

La modificaciones que pueden ser importantes son: Antes del igual preferí guardar la pantalla a texto, para no tener que estar excluyendo luego el igual, el ciclo for empieza desde el segundo numero, el resultado la primera vez es igual al primer numero, los operadores también se salta el primer operador ya que debería ser un espacio vació "", la x no me resulto identificarla de esa forma así que la reemplace en la revisión, espero te sirva y puedas sacar lo que mejor te funcione de aquí.